# Add dead code warning of C code to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c, code-coverage, visual-studio-2022

I use Visual Studio 2022 to build my C project and OpenCppCoverage to check the coverage.

With these tools, I don't find how to find C functions (static & public) that aren't called.
The /Zi option may not produce a PDB with the uncalled function and OpenCppCoverage is unable to detect it:

dead Code

[image: 1]

As the goal is to detect dead code, one option is to add a warning to visual studio 2022 compilator or linker to raise an error in case of unused function as gcc or to produce a PDB that contain information about the uncalled function (The second option may not work).

Anyone have an idea to detect dead code with these tools?

Comment: Ok, I post it in Msdn forum

Comment: Bump up the warning level to 4 and you'll get [c4505](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4505)

Comment: I have enabled all warning with /Wall option

Comment: I have tried with `#pragma warning(4:4505)` clean & build, no changes

Comment: Works just fine on my machine.  I'd guess you didn't try to build the Release configuration.

Comment: I have try it and it doesn't work neither.
Version: Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.2.3.
Compilation option: `/Wall /Od /MP /Zi`. I check with /O2 too.
That strange

Comment: Do you also check for static & inlined uncalled functions? As the uncovered line of "public" functions seems to be properly detected as unexercise code in openCppCoverage (but I don't have the warning).